# Avoid using v-if ... v-if ... v-if ... v-else

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I want to find out if it is possible to avoid using v-if ... v-if ... v-if ... v-else when rendering my items in a component.

**My Problem:**
I want to translate words from english to the selected language, for example, I have a list of languages to choose from and a set of words, dog, cat etc. Now if the user selects Dutch the word dog should be translated to Dutch, and if the user selects Italian, the word should be translated to Italian.

**Currently:**
I get my words in their different languages from my store as an object.

```
dog: {
  en: 'dog',
  de: 'hond',
  es: 'perro'
},
cat: {
  en: 'cat',
  de: 'kat',
  es: 'gata'
}
```

So basically, I thought maybe if i could do something like this:

```
<div v-for="(animal, index) in animals" key="index" LANG="en">
    {{ animal.LANG }}
</div>
```

And in doing so if I change the LANG from 'en' to 'de' it will change to Dutch. Well I know this is not possible...

**What I need:**
Basically I need a solution where I can change the word displayed when changing the language. Either on after binding the data, or maybe by changing the data from what I get to something like this...

```
{
  en: {
   dog: 'dog',
   cat: 'cat'
  },
  de: {
   dog: 'hond',
   cat: 'kat'
  },
  es: {
   dog: 'perro',
   cat: 'gata'
  }
}
```

Or any other option that will work without doing a bunch of if statements to do conditional rendering.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like your original plan should work if you use `{{ animal[LANG] }}` instead of `{{ animal.LANG }}`.

Comment: @0x5453 that works 100%. Thanks!

Comment: `de` is German btw, `nl` is Dutch

Comment: I would advise to use vue-18n : https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/ or nuxt-18n https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/